# Is it possible to do a pre-4.0 equivalent of UIView transitionWithView using Core Animation?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiview, core-animation, transition

I have an iPad 3.2 project where if you swipe left or right, it goes to a duplicate view with all the elements updated with the new data. However, in iOS 4.0 you can use `transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:` on a single view to do the same thing.

So my question is, using Core Animation, can I do the same thing in iOS 3.2? I'm badly running out of RAM because having a duplicate view (a very complicated view) is using up a lot of memory and I'm running into memory warnings.

Thanks!

:-Joe

Comment: I'm curious as to how the non-block method (the old way) will save on memory usage. I have some complex views, some of which will be loaded two or three at a time. I'm contemplating moving to the new block method, but may reconsider if there's a performance hit. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[self.view addSubview:myNewView];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:transition forView:view cache:YES];
// do view modifications that you did in the animations block
CGRect frame = myOldView.frame;
myNewView.frame = frame;
frame.origin.x = 320;
[myOldView setFrame:frame];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks! I also need to know though, are there push left or push right transition types? I can only see page curl and flip...

Comment: there is none, but in this case, i'll just change the frame.origin.x of the view, this will animate by itself using the duration ;)

Comment: but doesn't that mean you still need two views, one on screen and one off screen?

Comment: if you want to push a view "out", set it's frame.origin.x just out of the screen. after the commitAnimations call the removeFromSuperView. What it will do is animate you're view to go out of screen. Then, you can safely remove it and focus on you new view on screen

Comment: yeah the problem with that is that I need a second view to push in at the same time, or the user will be left with a blank page.

Comment: I updated my answer with what you need (approximately, non tested)